# Objective C. UIView gradient background frame does not fit view bounds

Tags: objective-c, uiview, background, gradient

I have created two UIViews in the Storyboard. Now, I am trying to set a gradient background for both:

```
-(void)drawView
{
    // Set the Views Background Color
    [self.depMetarView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.destMetarView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Draw a custom gradient
    CAGradientLayer *depMetarGradient = [IGABackgroundLayer gradientBlue];
    CAGradientLayer *destMetarGradient = [IGABackgroundLayer gradientBlue];
    depMetarGradient.frame = self.depMetarView.bounds;
    destMetarGradient.frame = self.destMetarView.bounds;
    [self.depMetarView.layer insertSublayer:depMetarGradient atIndex:0];
    [self.destMetarView.layer insertSublayer:destMetarGradient atIndex:0];

    // Round button corners
    [self.depMetarView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.depMetarView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [self.destMetarView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.destMetarView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];

    // Apply a 1 pixel, black border
    [self.depMetarView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self.depMetarView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
    [self.destMetarView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self.destMetarView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
}
```

Now, this is what I get:

[image]

I understand there is something wrong with the bounds of the view. Tried this:

```
CGRect depViewBounds = CGRectMake(self.depMetarView.frame.origin.x,self.depMetarView.frame.origin.y,self.depMetarView.frame.size.width, self.depMetarView.frame.size.height);
[self.depMetarView setBounds:depViewBounds];
```

...but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
CGRect depViewBounds = CGRectMake(self.depMetarView.frame.origin.x,self.depMetarView.frame.origin.y,self.depMetarView.frame.size.width, self.depMetarView.frame.size.height);
```

this:

```
CGRect depViewBounds = CGRectMake(0,0,self.depMetarView.frame.size.width, self.depMetarView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: I did. Did not help. Thanks, anyways.